# A question regarding the conjunction : neither...nor

Tags: conjunctions, neither-nor

I have a question in regards to the usage of ***neither..nor***.

I know that the typical and correct structure is:

(1) ***He is neither fat nor thin***.

But what about this:

(2) ***He is neither fatter nor thinner than his brother***.

Is (2) grammatically correct?

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> (2) **He is neither fatter nor thinner than his brother.**

is a correct sentence. You can use it safely.